# Error in XML document, browser will not display

Tags: xml

When I try to run this XML document in chrome, it just says

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error
```

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

```
<?xml version=“1.0” standalone=“yes”?>
<Projects>
  <Project>
    <Name>ProductX</Name>
    <Number>1</Number>

  </Project>
  <Project>
    <Name>ProductY</Name>
    <Number>2</Number>

  </Project>
</Projects>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the proper quotes. Change the first line from:

```
<?xml version=“1.0” standalone=“yes”?>
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
```